# Winforms Databinding to element in array

Tags: winforms

I have a string array and want to bind to this array with some text boxes on a windows form

The array has a fixed length of 5 elements, on my form I have 5 text boxes, I want to bind textbox1 to element 1 of the string array, textbox2 to element 2 of the string array and so on.

How do I go about that? Is it even possible?

txtMonth1.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", bsReport, "LabelName(0)", True))
txtMonth2.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", bsReport, "LabelName(1)", True))
etc
etc

Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can bind `TextBoxes` to individual elements of an array.

Something like below:

```
txtMonth1.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", bsReport[0], "LabelName(0)", True))  
txtMonth2.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", bsReport[1], "LabelName(1)", True))
```